# Ruby replace only exact matching string with another string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I solve following problem?

I have a html string like following one:

```
<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>
```

Now I'd like to replace for example only

```
"aaa"
```

with

```
"<div class='special'>aaa</div>"
```

new string after replace:

```
<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>
```

So I´d like a generic replacer, which only replace an exact matching string. "aaa" was just an example. It could also be "bb" or "two words" (=> two words, so text.split won't work in my opinion).

Anybody an idea for such an dynamic find, match and replacer?

I tried it already like following:

```
items = ["aaa", "a", "aa", "aa b", "c"]
text = "<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
words = text.split => ["<p>aaa,", "b", "aa", "aaaaa?<br/>Next", "possible", "text", "b", "bb", "aa", "b.</p>"]
new_words = []

words.each do |w|
   items.each do |item|
     if w == item
       w = '<div class="special">#{item}</div>'
     end
   end
  new_words << w
end
text = new_words.join(" ")
```

Result:

```
"<p>aaa, b <div class='special'>aa</div> aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb <div class='special'>aa</div> b.</p>"
```

But it should be:

```
"<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b <div class='special'>aa</div> aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb <div class='special'>aa b</div>.</p>"
```

My biggest problems are:

- Special characters like ",.?()%€"-characters at the end of a string
  => "aaa," from the example
- Substrings with same parts => like "aaa" and "aa"
- Two words as one item => like "aa b" from the example

Someone an idea for fixing my problems?

EDIT: something is only a placeholder for my replacement.. my real replacement could also be:

```
%Q( <dfn title="#{strip_tags item.text}">#{item.name}</dfn> )
```

item.text could be everything => could contain also "aaa"
item.name is for example "aaa"

So multiple gsub would replace also already replaced content.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) (not `gsub`)

```
s = "<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
# => "<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
match = "aaa"
# => "aaa"
replacement = "<div class='special'>aaa</div>"
# => "<div class='special'>aaa</div>"
s.sub match, replacement
# => "<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
"<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>" == _
# => true
```

Comment: but if the string is "<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.aaa.</p>" that would not work?

Comment: It would not work *if you kept the contents of the* `match` *variable the same.* If you have a different string then you can either change the the `match` variable via `match = "b bb"` (or whatever it is in the string you wish to match), or, probably better, edit your question and let us know how the strings are changing and how you know which portion to grab.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear whether there is a single instance of `aaa` or multiple, and whether you want them all replaced, or just the first one.

This will replace just the first:

```
text = "<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
text.sub(/\b(aaa)\b/, %q"<div class='special'>\1</div>")
=> "<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
```

This will replace all occurrences:

```
text = "<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>" * 2
=> "<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p><p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"

text.gsub(/\b(aaa)\b/, %q"<div class='special'>\1</div>")
=> "<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p><p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
```

You can put `"aaa"` into a variable and find it by interpolating that target into the pattern:

```
target = 'aaa'
text.gsub(/\b(#{ target })\b/, %q"<div class='special'>\1</div>")
=> "<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p><p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
```

Regular expressions have the `\b` (word-break) marker, which makes it easy to define words, or substring, matches. You can replace `"aaa"` with multiple words also.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression, [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a great place to learn and test out your expressions. For more information on how to use gsub check out [Jayfields Blog post](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/10/ruby-regular-expression-replace.html). This may not fit all your use cases for this problem so you may need to modify it.

```
    str.gsub /^<p>a{3}/, "<div class='special'>aaa</div>"


   What this says is starting at the beginning of the string (^) 
   find <p> and 3 assurances of the letter a.
```

Comment: It should be `sub` not `gsub`, as the OP only wants the first match and didn't specify that it would always be next to the tag.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the replacer method you wanted (using gsub, of course):

```
def replacer(orig,pattern,replace)
  orig.gsub(/#{pattern}(\s|\.|,)/,replace+'\1').to_s
end

2.0.0dev :001 > def replacer(orig,pattern,replace)
2.0.0dev :002?>     orig.gsub(/#{pattern}(\s|\.|,)/,replace+'\1').to_s
2.0.0dev :003?>   end
 => nil 
2.0.0dev :004 >  replacer("<p>aaa, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>", "aaa", "<div class='special'>aaa</div>")
 => "<p><div class='special'>aaa</div>, b aa aaaaa?<br/>Next possible text b bb aa b.</p>"
```