# How to get gsub to replace IP address, rather than just a part of an IP address?

Tags: ruby

Here's my sample data:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.11
```

In bash, I could simply do `cat file.txt | grep -w 192.168.1.1` and it will *only* grab 192.168.1.1, not 192.168.1.11

However, in Ruby, when I'm trying to replace `192.168.1.1`, it actually replaces `192.168.1.11` as well. Here's what I'm doing:

```
replace_array = ['192.168.1.1','x','xx','xx]
replace_array.each {|s| data.gsub!(/#{s}/i, "[redacted]")}
```

but this leaves `192.168.1.11` looking like `[redacted]1` as shown in the example below:

```
2.5.8 :005 > replace_array = ["192.168.1.1","x","xx","xxx"]
 => ["192.168.1.1", "x", "xx", "xxx"]
2.5.8 :006 > data = "192.168.1.1\n192.168.1.11"
 => "192.168.1.1\n192.168.1.11"
2.5.8 :007 > replace_array.each {|s| data.gsub!(/#{s}/i, "[redacted]")}
 => ["192.168.1.1", "x", "xx", "xxx"]
2.5.8 :008 > data
 => "[redacted]\n[redacted]1"
2.5.8 :009 >
```

Just simply trying to replace an exact match with gsub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized that the answer was simply adding `\b` before and after the string, as follows:

```
replace_array.each {|s| data.gsub!(/\b#{s}\b/i, "[redacted]")}
```

Problem solved.

Reference: [Ruby replace only exact matching string with another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960385/ruby-replace-only-exact-matching-string-with-another-string)

Answer (score 0):

It **is** replacing the first match, just not the way you expect. The first pattern in your array should be `'^192.168.1.1$'` if you want it to match the entire string instead of just part of it.

Comment: Replacing the first match isn't the problem. It's the fact that the second array element was being replaced as well. I don't have control over what's being put in the array either so I was just trying to figure out a way to take the given date and apply the solution. Thanks!